# What else implemented JSR-330?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I'm writing some code using JSR-330 annotations and I want to test it against (or using) various implementations.

Currently I've done with

1. dagger
2. dagger2
3. hk2
4. spring

Are there any other implementations?

Note that I'm not talking about CDI but DI.

Comment: [guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JSR330)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [tapestry](https://tapestry.apache.org/using-jsr-330-standard-annotations.html)?

> JSR-330 annotations can be used for injection in Tapestry 5.3 and later.

Answer (score 3):

CDI is the Java standard for Contexts and Dependency Injection and JSR-330 is a subset of it which it fully supports. Actually we extracted JSR-330 out of CDI (JSR-299) back then. So not sure why you distinguish strictly between 330 and CDI.

Apache OpenWebBeans https://openwebbeans.apache.org is a CDI 2.0 implementation in only 500kB. So that's not an argument neither.

The reason why I suggest to use CDI instead JSR-330 (atinject) is that the later only defines the consumer part - but not how to connect and create those components.